# $j$-$\omega$ method alternating current circuit help

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

I'm suppose to calculate the current and the phase angle. Can someone please tell me if this is the correct solution?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Also, please do not post formulae as screenshots, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead.